# How to improve the precision-recall scores as negative labels in test set is increased

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, data-science

Consider the below scenario:
I have batches of data whose features and labels have similar distribution.

Say something like 4000000 negative labels and 25000 positive labels

As its a highly imbalanced set, I have undersampled the negative labels so that my training set (taken from one of the batch) now contains 25000 positive labels and 500000 negative labels.

Now I am trying to measure the precision and recall from a test set after training  (generated from a different batch)
I am using XGBoost with 30 estimators.

Now if I use all of 40000000 negative labels, I get a (0.1 precsion and 0.1 recall at 0.7 threshold) worser precision-recall score than if I use a subset say just 500000 negative labels(0.4 precision with 0.1 recall at 0.3 threshold)..

What could be a potential reason that this could happen?

Few of the thoughts that I had:

1. The features of the 500000 negative labels are vastly different from the rest in the  overall 40000000 negative labels.
   But when I plot the individual features, their central tendencies closely match with the subset.

Are there any other ways to identify why I get a lower and a worser presicion recall, when the number of negative labels increase so much?

Are there any ways to compare the distributions?

Is my undersampled training a cause for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand this, we first need to understand how precision and recall are calculated. For this I will use the following variables:

P - total number of positives

N - total number of negatives

TP - number of true positives

TN - number of true negatives

FP - number of false positives

FN - number of false negatives

It is important to note that:

P = TP + FN

N = TN + FP

Now, precision is TP/(TP + FP)

recall is TP/(TP + FN), therefore TP/P.

Accuracy is TP/(TP + FN) + TN/(TN + FP), hence (TP + TN)/(P + N)

In your case where the the data is imbalanced, we have that N>>P.

Now imagine some random model. We can usually say that for such a model accuracy is around 50%, but that is only if the data is balanced. In your case, there will tend to be more FP's and TN's than TP's and FN's because a random selection of the data has more liklihood of returning a negative sample.

So we can establish that the more % of negative samples N/(T+N), the more FP and TN we get. That is, whenever your model is not able to select the correct label, it will pick a random label out of P and N and it is mostly going to be N.

*Recall* that FP is a denominator in precision? This means that precision also decreases with increasing N/(T+N).

For recall, we have neither FP nor TN in its derivation, so will likely not to change much with increasing N/(T+N) . As can be seen in your example, it clearly stays the same.

Therefore, I would try to make the data balanced to get better result. A ratio of 1:1.5 should do.
You can also use a different metric like the F1 score that combines precision and recall to get a better understanding of the performance.

Also check some of the other points made [here on how to combat imbalance data](https://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I am specifically curious about  "In your case, there will tend to be more FP's and TN's than TP's and FN's because a random selection of the data has more liklihood of returning a negative sample." Is there any documentation or papers that support this? I want to understand how to make my model resilient to reduce this likelihood.

Comment: @dev_vin I couldn't really find a paper detailing this out but you can check similar questions with similar answers [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41537/regarding-precision-and-recall-for-the-highly-unbalanced-validation-data-set)  and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39105626/unbalanced-labels-better-results-in-confusion-matrix). The idea is that since you have more negatives, most of the results of the classification by your model will also be negatives. Both FP and TN are negatives (FP + TN = N)